# Error downloading remote audio file with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to download remote audio files using AsyncTask which works just fine  for [this](http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/birds/birds001.mp3) but doesn't work for [this](http://sdmedia.playser.cadenaser.com/Podcast/2015/7/29/000WB0820620150729015306.mp3) url  .

When I try to debug it says "Breakpoint reached in thread main" when code reaches this line.

> InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

The code works perfectly when I use the 1st url I mentioned before making me unsure of what exactly is going wrong.

Here's the complete code:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        File newAudioFile = null;
        File oldAudioFile = null;
        try {
            //String remoteURL = url[0];
            Log.i(TAG, " url in AsyncTast= " + url[0]);
            IdHasher idHasher = new IdHasher();
            String fileName = idHasher.getHashedId(url[0]); // get hashed name of file from URL.

            // define path for new directory in DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS folder.
            File localFileDirectory = new File(String.valueOf(downloadDirectoryPath), audioCacheDirectory);

            if (!localFileDirectory.exists()) { // make directory if it doesn't exist.
                localFileDirectory.mkdirs();
                Log.i(TAG, " directories made");
            }

            oldAudioFile = new File(localFileDirectory, fileName + ".mp3");

            if (!oldAudioFile.isFile()) { // if file doesn't exist download it.

                Log.i(TAG, " new file downloaded");
                // download remote file
                URL remoteURL = new URL(url[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) remoteURL.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();

                double remoteFileSize = connection.getContentLength();
                double freeMemoryOnPhone = checkFreeMemoryOnPhone();

                Log.i(TAG, " remote file size = " + ((remoteFileSize / 1024) / 1024) + " mb");
                Log.i(TAG, " free memory on phone = " + ((freeMemoryOnPhone / 1024) / 1024) + " mb");

                try {
                    newAudioFile = new File(localFileDirectory, fileName + ".mp3");// add extension mp3 to filename.
                    newAudioFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    newAudioFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "error creating file" + e.getMessage());
                }

                if (remoteFileSize <= freeMemoryOnPhone) { // download remote file only if there is enough space on available on the phone.

                    if (!localFileDirectory.exists()) { // make directory if it doesn't exist.
                        localFileDirectory.mkdirs();
                        Log.i(TAG, " directories made");
                    }

                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newAudioFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytecount = 0;

                    while ((bytecount = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) { // read audio file from input stream and write it on phone memory.
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytecount);
                    }
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    Log.i(TAG, " File " + fileName + ".mp3 downloaded");
                    Log.i(TAG, " playAudioFile called");
                    //  mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.fromFile(newAudioFile));
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, " not enough memory on phone to download remote audio file");
                }
            } else { // if file exists, play it
                Log.i(TAG, "file " + fileName + ".mp3 already exits");
                Log.i(TAG, "old file passed");
                //mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.fromFile(oldAudioFile));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        if (!(newAudioFile == null)) {
            return String.valueOf(newAudioFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(oldAudioFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        }// mp.start();// play audio file
        //  return String.valueOf(mp);
    }
```

NOTE: I'm starting the AsyncTask from a service. The service calls a few functions which eventually calls AsyncTask.

Comment: On three places you call mkdirs() for the same directory. No good. Moreover you should check the return value and not continue if it fails to make the dirs.

Comment: 'newAudioFile.createNewFile();'. Remove that statement. The file will be created by the FileOutputStream.

Comment: 'connection.setDoOutput(true);'. Remove that statement. You will not do output for a GET method.

Comment: Thank you so much pointing out the mistakes. The issue of being unable to download from the mentioned urls still remains but yes that helped take out the other problems.